# AChartEngine - setXLabelsPadding method not working

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to show X Axis labels with the padding of 10px from the X Axis and with the angle of -30 degree. Below is my code but it is not working it shows labels at its default location exact below the axis, I want 10px space between axis and labels.

Code :

```
mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(-30.0f);
```

Please help solving this issue.

Thanks.

## Edited

I am using custom labels not generated by AChartengine, is that causes this issue ?

Code :

```
public void initChart() {
    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mCurrentSeries = new TimeSeries("Dates");
    mDataset.addSeries(mCurrentSeries);
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mSeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mSeriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    mSeriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    mSeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(mSeriesRenderer);
}

public void setRenderingStyle() {
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ilink_blue));
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ilink_blue));
    mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAngle(-30.0f);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(3);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setYTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.graph_bodyfat));
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 50, 10, 10});
}
```

## Screenshot

[image: Graph Image]

Comment: I have just tried it and it works fine for me. Maybe post more code and a screenshot?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot can you please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because while using custom labels we are using

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
```

so when the **drawXLabels** method of XYChart.java called it gets length of labels **0** and does not go in side the loop that is the reason why it is not working.

I have attached the copy of fixed version.

By the way thanks for the help @Dan

Download link : ["AChartEngine-fixed-1.2.0.jar"](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8-_tP52V1PdVjUyS3ZLOC1teGM/edit?usp=sharing)

## Result :

[image: Result]

Comment: Hey Mohit, can you provide the patch file (or at least the whole source file)? Dan can use it for the next release, and the rest of us can use it to fix it in the meantime. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TheAwnryBear here is the source file [XYChart.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-_tP52V1PdT21XNFhSVlNRQjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks Mohit, it works perfectly! Dan should definitely incorporate this into the 1.2 release.

Comment: Hmm, actually it looks like it's already been fixed in the code: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=363 Awesome!

Comment: @MohitSoni, it gives this error on trying to display a simple bar chart   java.lang.ClassCastException:org.chartengine.renderer .SimpleSeriesRenderercannot be cast to org.chartengine.renderer .XYSeriesRenderer (XYChart.java :247 )

It was not giving any error on using 1.1 version of AchartEngine

Comment: @MohitCharadva Hey I have the same issue with you which I wanted to add some padding between the axis with its label. I added the line above but it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried it and it does work. Try it with bigger values and you will get the X axis labels padding as much as you need.

Comment: I have changed the padding value between 10 to 300 but no change reflected on graph. It is still look same. Can you please provide the code ?

Comment: I have checked setXLabelsPadding only works if AChartEngine generates Labels itself. If we use custom labels than setXLabelsPadding is not working. Can you please fix this issue ?

Comment: Please post an issue with a patch here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list

Comment: I also am running into this same exact problem -- Mohit is absolutely correct; I've tried setting the padding anywhere from 10 to 1000, and it just stays at the default distance. BTW, I'm using version 1.1.0 of the library. @Dan, has this been fixed in SVN/git, or otherwise what is the status of the bug? If needed I can file the bug report but won't be able to provide a patch. It is looking like I'm going to need to draw the labels myself, but that's a last resort! :) Thanks all for reading.